# create a list of files to be deleted

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a search-and-destroy type program which I need it to do is search all directories with a certain file-name and append them to a list. after that delete all those files...not objects in list or the list...

```
    import os
file_list=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path-to-dir'):
       for f_name in files:
              if f_name.startswith("file-name"):
                     file_list.append(f_name)
```

I could write up to appending part of the code but I don't know next...

Some help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a file from your computer, use `os.remove()`. It takes **full path to the file** as it's parameter, so instead of calling `os.remove("infectedFile.dll")` you would call `os.remove("C:/program files/avira/infectedFile.dll")`

So your `file_list` should contain **full paths** to the files, and then just call:

```
for file in file_list:
    os.remove(file)
```

Comment: The full path must be added in the time of insertion into the `file_list`. It cannot be determined later.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `file_list.append(f_name)`. The `f_name` is only a bare name. You need to add the path to the file name in the time of processing, because you do not know where the file was found in the directory hierarchy:

```
        file_list.append(os.path.join(root, f_name))
```

The `root` variable contains the path during walking.

To make check whether your code works, just print the content of the list:

```
print('\n'.join(file_list))
```

Or you can do it in the loop to get ready for the later part:

```
for fname in file_list:
    print(fname)
```

Then you just add the `os.remove(fname)` to remove the file name:

```
for fname in file_list:
    print('removing', fname)
    os.remove(fname)
```

Comment: For the one who downvoted... Can you explain your objection? :)

Comment: Wasn't me downvoting, but what exactly does this add to my answer?

Comment: @Mahi: I did not tell you downvoted, and I did not expected it either. Surya Teja Karra is probably a beginner. My answer shows how to add the full path you mention. The `root` changes during walking. This way, it must be added when the item is inserted to the list. This is what your answer does not show.

Comment: But I do mention it. It leaves him something to figure out on his own, this site is not supposed to code programs for beginners, but to help them code it themselves.